# How to set a default <ui-view> within another <ui-view>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So what I'm trying to accomplish is: when the user clicks on the a-tag in **index.html** that leads them to the state "blogs", which is **main.html**, I want the ui-view element within **main.html** to automatically show **home.html**.

I have tried using `abstract: true, template: '<ui-view>` on the 'blogs' state and then giving the state 'blogs.home' an empty url so that it automatically shows up, but unfortunately that just makes it so that it populates the **index.html**'s ui-view element. Not what I want.

I'm trying to target the ui-view element within the **main.html** to be populated with the **home.html** as a default.

Any help would be appreciated, and I can clarify on anything that doesn't necessarily make sense in my explanation. Thanks in advance.

Here is my layout:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="header">
   <div class="title">
      <i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-magic fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;
      <h3>
          <span>AngularJS Blog</span>
      </h3>
   </div>
   <div class="nav-bar">
      <div class="nav-div nav-div-one">
         <a ui-sref="blogs"><i class="fa fa-archive fa-2x"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-div nav-div-two">
         <a ui-sref="newblog"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- VIEWS -->
<div ui-view class="main-fade"><div>
```

**main.html**

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="blog-container" ng-repeat="post in blog" ng-click="readPost(post._id)" ui-sref=".readblog">  
       <p><i class="fa fa-book"></i>&nbsp;{{ post.title }}</p>
       <p>by {{ post.author }}</p> 
       <p>{{ post.pubdate | date }}</p>
       <br>
       <div>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
       </div>
       <br><br>
       <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px;">
          <button id="deletePost" ng-click="deletePost(post._id)">Delete Blog</button>
          <button id="readPost" ng-click="readPost(post._id)" ui-sref=".readblog">Read Blog</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

**home.html**

```
    <div class="home">
        <h1>The place to write stuff down.</h1>
    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('blog-app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/blogs/home');

$stateProvider

.state('blogs', {
    url: '/blogs',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainController'
})

.state('blogs.home', {
    url: "",
    templateUrl: "views/home.html",
    MainController: "MainController"
})

.state('blogs.readblog', {
    url: "/readblog",
    templateUrl: "views/readblog.html",
    controller: "MainController"
})

.state('newblog', {
    url: '/newblog',
    templateUrl: "views/newblog.html",
    controller: "MainController"
}); 

}); //End Config. OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your views to do that.

```
<ui-view name="mainContent"></ui-view>
```

And in your config-

```
.state('blogs.home', {
    url: '/newblog',
    views: {
        'mainContent@blogs': {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "MainController"
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked. I got it to show the home.html. But is there a way to inject a new view into that ui-view element when I click the readPost button? Because now that isn't working like it should. :(

Comment: You should always point your views to `mainContent@blogs` if you want to replace that view